# How to store insert array values as separate record

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, optimization

i've one field in mySql table i.e Expanse and another field called Amount. [image]

now i want to break string in expanse and amount field on the basis of ';' and store each as a seperate record such that data in other fields i.e id and name remains unchanged. such that[image]

I am fetching record from orignal table and want to store this desired result in temporary table. while fetching record from orginal table i'm exploding expanse and amount string on the basis on ';'.

```
 $query="SELECT * FROM table";
 $result=mysql_query($query);
 while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
{
$newid=$row["id"];
$temp=explode(';',$row["expanse"]); 
$new=array_unique($temp);
//what to do after this ?


$temp2=explode(';',$row["amount"]); 
$new2=array_unique($temp2);
//what to do after this ? 
$query2="INSERT INTO table2 (id, $expanse,$amount)  VALUES   ('$newid','$new',$new2);
$result2=mysql_query($query2);
}

//after this i'll be inserting values in these variables into new temporary table that is having same structure so that my orignal data remain unchanged and new data as my need inserted into temporary table.
```

Hope you get my question.

Comment: after $result2 write second query to insert into temp data.

Comment: You can save that as per your need but if `id` is `primary key` then it will be unique always

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to iterate threw each record and again iterate threw each `;` delimitted values. `id` and `name` will be same for each record but `expanse` and `amount` will vary. Number of insert queries is depends on number of `;` delimitted values

```
 $query="SELECT * FROM table";
 $result=mysql_query($query);

 while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
{

    $id = $row["id"]; // duplicating for each 
    $name = $row['name']; // duplicating for each
    $expance_array = explode(';',$row["expanse"]); 
    $amount_array = explode(';',$row["amount"]); 

    /* count of expance_array and amount_array will be same always as per your idea */

    for($i=0;$i<count($expance_array);++$i) {

        $expanse = $expance_array[$i]; 
        $amount  =  $amount_array[$i];

        /* now insert $id   $name  $expanse  $amount  into the table*/
        $query2="INSERT INTO table2 (id, name , expanse, amount)  VALUES ($id,'$name','$expanse' , $amount");
        $result2=mysql_query($query2);

    }

}
```

Comment: I got your logic . but could you tell that will it work if there were more than one record present in db. in my situation i could have thousands of records in my orignal table 1.  Thank you

Comment: yes it will work. because each iteration of while loop represent a different record. if you have 1000 records and your expense is like `lunch;dinner;tea` then 3 * 1000 = 3000 insert queries will be required.

Answer (score 0):

You will need a separate INSERT for every item in the array.

```
function getInsertQueries($id, $expanse, $amount){
    $insertQueries = array();
    $expanses = array_unique(explode(";", $expanse));
    $amounts = array_unique(explode(";", $amount));
    if(count($expanses) == count($amounts)){
        for($i=0;$i<count($expanses);$i++){
            $insertQueries[] = "INSERT INTO table2 (id, expanse, amount) VALUES ('$id', '$expanses[$i]', '$amounts[$i]')";
        }
    }
    return $insertQueries;
}


$query="SELECT * FROM table";
$result=mysql_query($query);
while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    $insertQueries = getInsertQueries($row["id"], $row["expanse"], $row["amount"]);
    foreach($insertQueries as $query){
        mysqli_query($query);
    }
}
```